# NullReferenceException usando HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, html-agility-pack, nullpointerexception

Gostaria de saber quantas *tags* `<a>` existem dentro de uma `div`, mas a Exceção `NullReferenceException` é disparada ao chegar no XPath.

```
var baseURL = "AQUI VAI A MINHA URL";

var client = new HtmlWeb();

var pagina = client.Load(baseURL);

var quantidade = pagina.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='react - root']/section/main/article/div/div[1]/div[1]/a").Count;
```

Ele não conseguiu chegar no caminho ou estou fazendo algo de errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método `SelectNodes()` retorna um nulo se não achar nenhum nó que atende ao especificado. Aí o código tenta pegar a contagem e gera este erro. Mas pode ser que tenha algum erro anterior para gerar o nulo indevidamente. Isto deve resolver:

```
var nos = pagina.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='react - root']/section/main/article/div/div[1]/div[1]/a");
var quantidade = nos == null ? 0 : nos.Count;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/NullVerification.cs).

Comment: Entendi, esta explicado então.
Porque sera que ele não esta achando nada? Dentro de div[1]/a tenho três tags <a> e gerei esse caminho no Chrome usando o inspetor de elementos.

Comment: Aí já não sei dizer.

Comment: É, complicado mesmo.. tudo bem, muito obrigado.

Comment: Você sabe se esse HTML está sendo gerado dinamicamente por JavaScript na tela? O HtmlAgilityPack não execute os trechos de código JavaScript que recebe da requisição, então HTML gerado por JS não será capturado pela biblioteca. Se for isso o AngleSharp tem suporte para uma engine de JS (só que também não é 100% funcional, mas vale a pena tentar).